# Desktop Database tool like Glom

Tags: database, orm

I'm looking for a (Windows) stand-alone desktop database tool, where I can create database schemas and manipulate the data within the database. *Glom* is providing this features, unfortunately, it is not maintained anymore.
The database should also be available for third party application, e.g. I insert data into the database, but I can read the content with a python script. So a backend using databases like SQLite or PostgreSQL would be great. Thank you.